# How to write OnClick to an image tag in Response.Write

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, ajax

```
Response.Write("<img src = 'Edit-icon.png' height='20' width='20' onClick = 'passValuesToInput();'>");
```

i've written this in aspx.cs but the javascript function is not being called. This isn't working. Why?

Comment: You will have to show more code for anyone to give you a good reason, though most likely you haven't defined the function _before_ the image element? If you move that code to the head it probably works

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using single quote `'`, use double quote `"` and escape it with another double quote

```
Response.Write("<img src=""Edit-icon.png"" height=""20"" width=""20"" onClick=""passValuesToInput();"">")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Response.Write("<img src = 'Edit-icon.png' height='20' width='20' onClick = '\"passValuesToInput();\"'>");
```